# Managing quiz collection

Tags: design, architecture, data, scalability

I am creating a simple application where users will be shown random quizzes one at a time and they have to answer them. Each quiz has a category and many tags, right now I have stored quizzes in a single flat file but it seems that I may need many quizzes in near future and hence my solution isn't scalable at all.

What I thought is to keep quizzes in separate folders which would be named after category but the issue is then how to keep the sequence number of the quizzes in order.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Databases seem the obvious solution.

Comment: And SQLite seems to be the obvious database to choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text files are probably the best way to go, for now. You can format them however you want. If your metadata is simple enough you probably don't even need XML, just some token to separate header data from the actual quiz such as:

```
tags: health, happines
title: Are you happy and Healthy?
----
Question 1: blah blah blah...
```

Here, you have header lines containing metadata, to indicate what the tags are for this quiz, and the title. Then a very simple token: `----` on its own line, then the rest of the quiz follows, until the end of the file. You can add other header lines if you need them.

If you want to keep them all in once file, come up with a separate token to separate the quizzes. Something simple like `////` on its own line should work. Multiple quzzes would look like:

```
////
tags: health, happiness
title: Quiz 1
----
Question 1: blah blah blah...
(other questions)
////
tags: pets, cheese
title: Quiz 2
----
Question 1: bleh bleh bleh...
(other questions)
////
```

Once you have decided on a format for the quiz files, you can load them into an in-memory cache so you don't need to keep reloading them. Build the cache once, when your program starts, and then that's it!

If you find you have *so many* quizzes that loading text files is too slow, or your metadata gets too complicated to keep in simple header lines, or you want to start cross-referencing quizzes and users' answers, you might want to look into setting up a relational database (such as MySQL or Postgres - both are free!) to store quizzes and quiz-related data.

Comment: What if I have 1000 quizzes?

Comment: @CodeYogi: Loading 1000 quiz files from disk shouldn't be that difficult on decent hardware. And if you only load them once, and keep them in a cache in memory, it should be very fast. What other concerns do you have about 1000 quizzes?

Answer (score 1):

It takes a LOT of quizzes to have scale problems.

What format are you saving the text in?

In a flat file [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) is common. XML is designed specifically for data.  Some pretty good search tools for XML.

Past XML is a full database.  Many free databases available.

Comment: I am storing them in `.py` file, also if I have 100s of quizes them managing them might be an issue.

Comment: Not familiar with .py but from my limited research they are script files.  I specifically state XML as that is a data format. A thousand records in (properly designed) XML is very fast. I have done 10,000 records and still had searches in less than 1 second.

Comment: @CodeYogi: It sounds like you are storing your data in your program file. This is generally not a good idea for data like this.